# TypeError when redirecting to Django URL

Tags: python, django

Very simple one but cannot seem to find the issue :

```
TypeError at /userlookup/foo
userlookup() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

**views.py**

```
def userlookup (request, username):

     if request.method == "GET":

        UserId = User.objects.get(user=username).id
        UserPosts = Post.objects.filter(user=UserId)
        UserPosts = list(UserPosts.order_by("-timestamp").all())

        p_all = Paginator(UserPosts, 10)
        page_number = request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj_all = p_all.get_page(page_number)

        return render(request, "network/userlookup.html",{
        "page_obj_all": page_obj_all,
        "allposts": UserPosts,
        })
```

**url.py**

```
path("user/<str:username>", views.userlookup, name="userlookup"),
```

**html** (Properly looping, but shortening for visibility)

```
(Some Stuff)
<div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title" id="Username">{{ allpost.user }}</h5>
              <a href="{% url 'userlookup' allpost.user%}">{{ allpost.user }} 's profile</a>
              <p>User ID = {{ allpost.user.id }}</p> 
</div>
(Some Stuff)
```

**Question : Why the error?**

- I understand that allpost.user = foo.
- I pass "foo" to the URL called userlookup.
- The URL do accept a STR called username.
- My function then grab the username, fetch the data based on the username and (should) return "username/foo" with the relevant data.

Hope you can help!

EDIT :

**Models**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following = models.ManyToManyField("User", blank=True, related_name="following_name")
    follower = models.ManyToManyField("User", blank=True, related_name="follower_name")
    
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "following": [user.profile for user in self.following.all()],
            "follower": [user.profile for user in self.follower.all()],
        }

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=350, null=True, blank=True)
    like = models.ManyToManyField("User", blank=True, related_name="like_amount")

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "timestamp": self.timestamp.strftime("%b %-d %Y, %-I:%M %p"),
            "post": self.post,
            "like": [user.post for user in self.like.all()],
        }
```

Comment: Does `allpost.user` returns the username? Remember `str:` should match any non-empty  string. So if no username than it throws error.

Comment: Hello @Raja Simon , allpost.user do return "foo". 
I also attempted to pass the user ID by using allpost.user.id and changing the path to <int:id> with the function arguments as def userlookup (request, id), but I receive the same error regarding the "unexpected keyword argument".

Comment: Is it possible to update your question with `Post`? I can't able to find any other reasons.

Comment: @Raja Simon I have added the Model for you

Comment: @Raja Simon I have figured it out, I was calling views.userlookup while my function was in test.py ... Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Calling the wrong .py file in the URL.

views.userlookup => tests.userlookup